# Script load failed service worker on PWA

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

On my PWA application I have successfully registered a service worker. Some users on Safari are experiencing this error `Script https://app.com/service-worker.js load failed` Note that I was still able to view the service worker in the dev tools despite the error (it was activated status).

It is not clear what this error means. It is not impacting their experience but I am afraid it might cause issues later on.

Here is my `service-worker.js` - Note we cannot have any caching in our application. We enabled the service worker just so we can have add to home screen capability on Android.

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST.filter(() => false));

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
  event.waitUntil(caches.open('app').then((cache) => cache.addAll([])));
});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .keys()
      .then((cacheNames) => Promise.all(cacheNames.map((cacheName) => caches.delete(cacheName)))),
  );
});
```